# Grails 3.2.8 - Taglib ˜g not acessible from controller

Tags: grails, controller, taglib

Im trying to use the following command on a controller:

```
String html = g.render(template: 'etiqueta', model: [user: user])
```

It works perfectly on another project of mine, using Grails 3.3.1. But on Grails 3.2.8 it doens't work! I'm trying to find a workaround without success.

I just started on a new job and I got stuck on this task because of this issue, it`s been a couple days now...

Does anyone know to solve this?

Comment: Does your template has <html> </html> tag? try removing this.

Comment: You should elaborate on "it doesn't work".  Is there an error message?  The template is rendered but has unexpected content?

Comment: I've found out that some plugins were removed from this project, like the gsp plugin. After adding it back the g namespace was resolved and i could use g.render. Now for some reason, none of the images is being displayed and a couple barcodes generated by a js are not showing too. I Have no ideia how to solve this.

Comment: post your GSP page that makes error and the Gradle config. Is there any error in the console? then post the stacktrace too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PageRenderer`.

```
class SomeController {

    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

    def someAction() {
        def html = groovyPageRenderer.render(template: 'etiqueta', model: [user: user])
        // ...
    }
}
```